# Finding the order of the product of disjoint cycles in $S_n$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$-symbols say $\{1,2, \cdots , n \}.$ Let $\sigma \in S_n,$ Let $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \cdots , \sigma_r$ be $r$ disjoint cycles in $S_n$ such that $\sigma =  \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \cdots \sigma_r.$ Then show that $$\text {Ord}\ (\sigma) = \text {lcm}\ \{\text {Ord}\ (\sigma_1), \text {Ord}\ (\sigma_2), \cdots , \text {Ord}\ (\sigma_r)  \}.$$

Here I observe that any two disjoint cycles will commute with each other. Tempted by this observation and a theorem I read in my first course in group theory (which states that **Let $G$ be a finite group and $a,b \in G$ be two elements of $G$ which commute with each other. Let $\text {Ord}\ (a) = m$ and $\text {Ord}\ (b) = n.$ If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime to each other then $\text {Ord}\ (ab) = mn$**) I have tried the whole long day to prove a lemma which is as follows.

**Lemma** $:$ Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $a,b \in G$ be two elements commute with each other. Then $\text {Ord}\ (ab) = \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {Ord}\ (a), \text {Ord}\ (b) \right ).$

I saw that if we can prove this lemma the required result follows. Just now I observed that it is false for every finite group of cardinality $\geq 2.$ Because if $G$ is a group with $|G| \geq 2$ then it contains a non-identity element say $a.$ Then I noticed $aa^{-1} = a^{-1}a = e.$ So $a$ always commutes with $a^{-1}.$ Also we have $\text {Ord}\ (a) = \text {Ord}\ (a^{-1}).$ So if the above lemma would hold then $$1 = \text {Ord}\ (e) = \text {Ord}\ (aa^{-1}) = \text {lcm}\ \{\text {Ord}\ (a), \text {Ord}\ (a^{-1}) \} = \text {Ord}\ (a).$$

This shows that $\text {Ord}\ (a) = 1 \implies a = e,$ which is a contradiction to our assumption. Hence the lemma is false.

Now I don't find any other approach to prove the required result. Can anybody please give me any suggestion regarding this?

Thanks for your valuable time.

**EDIT** $:$ I have managed to prove that $\text {Ord}\ (\sigma)\ \bigg |\ \text {lcm}\ \{\text {Ord}\ (\sigma_1), \text {Ord}\ (\sigma_2), \cdots , \text {Ord}\ (\sigma_r)  \}.$ How do I prove the other way round?

Comment: No see my lemma what I described @almagest. There I omitted the restriction you have mentioned.

Comment: I think I got it. Can I answer my own question?

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question. (If you know an answer, that is.)

Comment: @DanielFischer can you please check my answer?

Comment: Looks good. If you look closely, the key point is that the lemma in the question holds if you add the hypothesis that the subgroups generated by $a$ and $b$ respectively have trivial intersection. Your argument with the supports amounts to proving that hypothesis for the case of disjoint cycles. I expect you will have no problems proving the revised lemma, if $a$ and $b$ commute, and $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle = \{e\}$, then $\operatorname{ord}(ab) = \operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}(a), \operatorname{ord}(b))$ in general.

Comment: @DanielFischer the revised lemma is pretty straightforward. If $\text {ord}(ab)=m$ then we have $$(ab)^m = e \implies a^mb^m = e \implies a^m = b^{-m}.$$ Now $a^m \in \langle a \rangle$ and $b^{-m} \in \langle b\rangle.$ This shows that $a^m,b^{-m} \in \langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle \implies a^m,b^m \in \langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = \{e \}.$ So it follows that $a^m=b^m=e.$ So $\text{ord} (a)\ \big |\ m$ and $\text{ord} (b)\ \big |\ m.$ Hence it follows that $\text {lcm}\ \left (\text {ord} (a), \text {ord} (b) \right )\ \bigg |\ m.$ Am I right?

Comment: The other part i.e. $m\ \bigg |\ \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {ord} (a), \text {ord} (b) \right )$ is very easy which I already discussed and it can be done without having $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = \{e \}.$ Hence the equality follows.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Correct (to nobody's surprise). And then showing that $\langle \sigma\rangle \cap \langle \tau\rangle = \{\operatorname{id}\}$ for disjoint cycles can be done shorter than your proof of $\operatorname{ord}(\sigma\tau) = \operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}(\sigma), \operatorname{ord}(\tau))$. $\sigma^k$ leaves everything in the support of $\tau$ fixed, $\tau^k$ everything in the support of $\sigma$, so everything in the intersection leaves both supports fixed. And the rest of course too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101714/discussion-between-math-maniac-and-daniel-fischer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have started from the stage where I got stuck in proving the above lemma. It is easy to show what I just mentioned in the edit is that $\text {Ord}\ (ab)\ \big |\ \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {Ord}\ (a), \text {Ord}\ (b) \right ).$ To prove equality we need to prove the other way round which is not true for arbitrary finite groups even if $a$ and $b$ commute. We are so lucky that the other part is true for our case. Why? Lets discuss.

Before proving the required result I noticed that if we can prove the following lemma we are through.

**Lemma** $:$ Let $\sigma, \tau \in S_n$ be two disjoint cycles. Then $\text {Ord}\ (\sigma \tau ) =  \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {Ord}\ (\sigma), \text {Ord}\ (\tau) \right ).$

For proving the equality in the lemma let us first introduce the following definition.

Let $\rho = (a_1,a_2, \cdots , a_r) \in S_n$ be an $r$-cycle. Then the support of $\rho$ is denoted by $\text {Supp}\ (\rho)$ and it is defined as $\text {Supp}\ (\rho) = \{a_1,a_2, \cdots , a_r \}.$ So $\text {Supp}\ (\rho)$ consists of those points in $\{1,2, \cdots, n \}$ which are disturbed by the operation of $\rho.$

**Observation** $:$ If $\rho,\rho' \in S_n$ are two cycles inverses of each other then $\text {Supp}\ (\rho) = \text {Supp}\ (\rho').$ (Because inverse cycles fix same points).

Now let us take two disjoint cycles $\sigma , \tau \in S_n.$ On contrary let us assume that $\text {Ord}\ (\sigma \tau) = m < \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {Ord}\ (\sigma), \text {Ord}\ (\tau) \right ).$ Then it is easy to see that $m\ \bigg |\  \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {Ord}\ (\sigma), \text {Ord}\ (\tau) \right ).$  Let us assume that $\sigma^m \neq \text {id}$ and $\tau^m \neq \text {id}$ for otherwise $m = \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {Ord}\ (\sigma), \text {Ord}\ (\tau) \right ),$ a contradiction to our assumption. Since fixed points of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are respectively fixed points of $\sigma^m$ and $\tau^m$ respectively it follows that $\text {Supp}\ (\sigma^m) \subseteq \text {Supp}\ (\sigma)$ and $\text {Supp}\ (\tau^m) \subseteq \text {Supp}\ (\tau).$ Since $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are disjoint cycles so we have $\text {Supp}\ (\sigma) \cap \text {Supp}\ (\tau) = \varnothing.$  Hence $\text {Supp}\ (\sigma^m) \cap \text {Supp}\ (\tau^m) = \varnothing.\ \ \ \ (*)$

Now since $\text {Ord}\ (\sigma \tau) = m$ so we have $$\begin{align*} (\sigma \tau)^m & = \text {id}  \implies \sigma^m \tau^m  = \text {id} \implies \sigma^m  = (\tau^m)^{-1} \end{align*}$$

So $\sigma^m$ is the inverse of $\tau^m.$ So from our **Observation** it follows that $\text {Supp}\ (\sigma^m) = \text {Supp}\ (\tau^m).$ Since $\sigma^m \neq \text {id}$ and $\tau^m \neq \text {id}$ it follows that $\text {Supp}\ (\sigma^m) = \text {Supp}\ (\tau^m) \neq \varnothing$ and hence $\text {Supp}\ (\sigma^m) \cap \text {Supp}\ (\tau^m) \neq \varnothing,$ which contradicts $(*).$ That implies either $\sigma^m = \text {id}$ or $\tau^m = \text {id}.$ But if one of $\sigma^m$ or $\tau^m$ is identity then by using the equation $\sigma^m \tau^m = \text {id}$ we find that the other is also an identity. So we must have $\sigma^m = \tau^m = \text {id}.$ This implies $\text {Ord}\ (\sigma)\ \big |\ m$ and  $\text {Ord}\ (\tau)\ \big |\ m.$ But it means that $\text {lcm}\ \left ( \text {Ord}\ (\sigma),\text {Ord}\ (\tau) \right )\ \bigg |\ m,$ which is a contradiction to our assumption that $m < \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {Ord}\ (\sigma), \text {Ord}\ (\tau) \right ).$ Hence our assumption is false. So $m \geq \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {Ord}\ (\sigma), \text {Ord}\ (\tau) \right ).$ But since $m\ \bigg |\  \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {Ord}\ (\sigma), \text {Ord}\ (\tau) \right )$ it follows that $m \leq  \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {Ord}\ (\sigma), \text {Ord}\ (\tau) \right ).$ Hence combining these two inequalities it follows that $m =  \text {lcm}\ \left (\text {Ord}\ (\sigma), \text {Ord}\ (\tau) \right ).$

**QED**